# How should i configure about images in pubsec.yml for nested structure

Tags: flutter

I've set simply the pubsec.yaml and it has been worked successfully as follows;

1. images/logo1.png
2. images/logo2.png

```dart
//pubsec.yml
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - images/
//indents are set appropriately
```

However, it doesn't work when I restructure as following and with no changings is pubsecyml;

1. images/main/logo1.png
2. images/sub/logo2.png

image_provider throws errors like

```dart
  Future<ui.Codec> _loadAsync(AssetBundleImageKey key, DecoderBufferCallback? decode, DecoderCallback? decodeDepreacted) async {
    if (decode != null) {
      ui.ImmutableBuffer? buffer;
      // Hot reload/restart could change whether an asset bundle or key in a
      // bundle are available, or if it is a network backed bundle.
      try {
        buffer = await key.bundle.loadBuffer(key.name);
      } on FlutterError {
        PaintingBinding.instance.imageCache.evict(key);
        rethrow;//here
      }
      if (buffer == null) {
        PaintingBinding.instance.imageCache.evict(key);
        throw StateError('Unable to read data');
      }
      return decode(buffer);
    }
```

ScreenShot for pubsec.yml
[image]

Comment: this should work ``assets:
    - images/
    - images/main/ 
    - images/sub/``

Comment: thanks for your comment! is these items should put with same indents?

Comment: sorry but console says: Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
No file or variants found for asset: images/main. pleae refer to my screenshot above

Comment: main and sub are folders right? images/main/ should work like @OMiShah said.

Comment: yes they are folders but flutter could not find it.

Comment: is images folder inside your lib folder or root folder?

Comment: it should be `images/main/` not `images/main`. Notice the last `/`

Comment: @ivo I'm really sorry for late reply. It finally worked and the problem was what you pointed out ! Thanks a lot !!